# Error in IE when setting element.style.height?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have a rather large script that is setting the height of five elements to one pixel. The script can be found here ( https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark/blob/master/modules/round.js ) and is throwing an error on line 39. The error is only thrown in IE 6 and 7. I can not for the life of me see anything wrong with this at all, any ideas anyone? Does IE have something against the height of div's? I have a running version of the whole library here ( http://flowdev.co.uk/spark.html ).

The error is as follows `style is null or not an object`.

It is only thrown once.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tested what's being selected in line 33?

`var top = Sizzle('div.spark-corner-top div', element[e]);`

My guess is that `top` may be empty.

Comment: But its width and background colour are applied perfectly.

Comment: @Wolfy86 Now use the IE Script Debugger and examine the actual object you have. The problem will be resolved therein. You can't `x.style.backgroundColor = y` if `x.style.height = z` throws that error. +1 for the answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help so far, I will give the debugger a go tomorrow and if you are right I will accept. +1 in the mean time though.

Comment: I just took the module out for now, when I go to reimplement it then I will run all these checks, you may well be right.